# convergence of a series - lebesgue

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\xi_n$ a sequence in $[0,1]$. Prove that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{{n^2|x-\xi_n|}^{1/2}}$$
converge for almost all $x\in [0,1]$ (Lebesgue measure)

Comment: Hint: Integrate the thing.

Answer (score 2):

For each $n$,

\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{|x - \xi_n|^{1/2}} &= \int_0^{\xi_n} \frac{dx}{(\xi_n - x)^{1/2}} + \int_{\xi_n}^1 \frac{dx}{(x - \xi_n)^{1/2}}\\
&= \int_0^{\xi_n} \frac{dx}{x^{1/2}} + \int_{\xi_n}^1 \frac{dx}{(x - \xi_n)^{1/2}}\\
&= 2\sqrt{\xi_n} + 2\sqrt{1 - \xi_n}.\\
\end{align}

Since $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{\xi_n} + \sqrt{1 - \xi_n}}{n^2} \le \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2} < \infty,$$ it follows that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2|x - \xi|^{1/2}}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, so it is convergent almost everywhere in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I think that the term $-2\sqrt{\xi_n}$ does not exists (line 4)

Comment: You mean $2\sqrt{1 - \xi_n}$? Since $0 \le \xi_n \le 1$, $1 - \xi_n \ge 0$, so the term $2\sqrt{1 - \xi_n}$ does exist.

Comment: The primitive is $2\sqrt{x-\xi_n}$, and you are integrating from $\xi_n$ to $1$.

Comment: It seems like what you were trying to say is that $-2\sqrt{\xi_n}$ should not be present in the formula. In that case, yes you're right. I made the correction.

Comment: Yes, Sorry for my bad English. Nice answer (+1)

Comment: If a series is integrable in $[0,1]$, does it mean that the series is convergent? Why is it so?

Comment: @Ri-Li no, but it implies the series converges *almost everywhere* in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, I think you skipped two steps here. First, we can interchange the sum and the integration because of MCT.

Comment: Then your argument shows that the integration is finite and then your next claim is based on the fact that if it is not convergent almost everywhere then there will be a set of measure positive where it diverges because the sequence of functions(partial sum of the series) is positive and monotone and hence we get a divergent integration( in measure theory a function is still integrable even if it is infinity) but we already proved that the integration is finite and hence contradiction.

Comment: I just tried to fill out the details, not to point out any error. Please let me know whether I am right or wrong!

Comment: @Ri-Li Your justification for interchanging sum and integral is correct. For the second piece, if $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function on a measure space $(X,\mu)$ with $\int_X f\, d\mu < \infty$, then $f < \infty$ a.e. $[\mu]$. Indeed, if $S$ is the set of points $x\in X$ where $f(x) = \infty$, then for each $n$, $S$ is contained in $S_n := \{x\in X: f(x) \ge n\}$. Thus, for each $n$, $\mu(S) \le \mu(S_n) \le 1/n\int_X f\, d\mu$. Since $n$ is arbitrary, $S$ has measure zero, as desired.